# How does Genesys Composer application different from the Eclipse RCP app

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

With Eclipse RCP application, one can create a stand-alone application (IDE) similar to eclipse.  How does this differ from the Genesys composer IDE. Genesys Composer is not a stand alone application, instead it just extends the existing Eclipse IDE and has its own features built on top of it.

What is the underlying technology (or framework) that is used to develop such applications  ?

Can you point me to the tutorials (if any) for developing such applications to extend the Eclipse IDE ?

Comment: This is just a set of Eclipse plugins that install in an existing Eclipse. They use the APIs documented extensively in the Eclipse Platform Plug-in Developer Guide. An RCP is just a set of plugins packaged in to an installable product.

Comment: @greg-449,  Thanks  for your response. So, you mean to say that RCP would have a _*.product_ associated whereas the plugin won't have that ? It would be great, if you point me to the API (or documents) which was used in the Eclipse Platform Plug-in Developer Guide !

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking. The plugins will be using many of the APIs to do things like define perspectives, views and editors in exactly the same way as the 'core' Eclipse (which is also just plugins using the same APIs).

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 for your reply.